# Запуск скрипта в фоновом режиме с выходом из оболочки

Tags: bash, linux

Появилась потребность по ssh запускать на linux-сервере процесс, который после запуска не возвращает консоль, а если закрыть ssh-сессию (хотя бы закрыв окно ssh-клиента), то процесс отключался. Соединяюсь с сервером через SSH.

Пробовал использовать tmux, но он сложный и использовать его я не хочу.

Пробовал использовать `$# nohup ping 127.0.0.1 &` но он почему то закрывался после отключения от консоли. Так и не понял как с ним работать.

Пробовал так же запускать команды с & но после просмотра их с помощью jobs и возврата к выполняемой команде с помощью fg не понял как свернуть команду опять. В общем так и не понял как запускать фоновые приложения с отключением от консоли.

Есть ещё  screen  команда, вот её разве что не смотрел. Кто знает как это делать то расскажите на пальцах.

Answer (score 2):

Поможет это:

```
screen <program name>
```

Answer (score 1):

Есть в баше такая встроенная команда - disown.